# Google Drive Security update - ResourceKeys

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to make changes when making API calls to Google drive API because of the security update they will enforce on the 10th September.

In a subset of files, it seems it will be needed to pass a specific header in Google Drive's API requests with the file's resourceKey if the key exists (Name of the header: X-Goog-Drive-Resource-Keys). Info can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resource-keys).

In the docs it is pointed that resource key of a file can be fetched with Google Drive's GET file method.

However from the article is unclear, that if it needs to be the admin of thee file to get that file, store the resource key and all calls afterwards made to that file from another person's perspective needs the resource key, including calling the **get file method**.

**Do we need to pass the resource key to the get file method in Google drive API or can we can fetch the ResourceKey with a user that already had permissions to the file before this security update and use the resource key to all other calls afterwards?**

Answer (score 0):

From the link:

> A file that is shared with the link can only be discovered by users that can access the file as a result of a type=user or type=group permission. Requests from users that only have access to these link-shared files via a type=domain or type=anyone permission, may require a resource key.

As long as you have the proper (user/group) permissions during the request, you will be able to access it without resource key. You only need it when the user only have the domain/anyone permission. And I think that it will still be needed in the get method if you don't have the proper permissions.

As for the storing the resource key and using it in future requests, that I am not sure as like you said, it wasn't provided in the information. But if the resource key is static (which is likely), then you will most likely be able to reuse it in the next requests.

Additional details [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685032?hl=en)

> On September 13, 2021, Drive applies a security update to make file sharing more secure. As an administrator, you can choose how to apply this update.

> This update changes the links used for some files. Access to impacted files won’t change for people who have already viewed them or who have direct access, but others might need to request access.

Comment: If that's like that, imagine you have multiple files from different users stored. You have 2 files, FileA and FileB and have 2 users UserA and UserB. If userA tried to access FileB via Google Drive API how can you now know beforehand what is the resourceKey that it is need to perform a GoogleDrive API operation? The only way I see possible is if userA be able to fetch the resource key from FileB and be mandatory that it uses it afterwards.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler if you provide group permissions to the users instead for those files or it isn't a viable option for your setup? @PedroFranco